# Cannot get ruby to parse my XML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm brand new to Ruby and having a hell of a time trying to do even a simple tree walk of my XML which looks like this:

```
<fx:Container>
    <fx:topic>Exchange rates</fx:topic>
    <fx:Provider>
        <fx:name>Standard Bank</fx:name>
    </fx:Provider>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2018-12-06">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1351"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="128.04"/>
            ... and more currencies
        </Cube>
        <Cube time="2018-12-05">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1301"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="129.36"/>
            ... and more currencies
        </Cube>
        ... and so on for more dates
    </Cube>
</fx:Container>
```

There's no DTD for the XML, and the naming of nodes is not under my control.

So if you imagine a class (ForEx) with three fields of date, currency and rate, then I just want to create a Ruby collection of ForEx instances uniquely keyed by date and currency (so I can put those into an SQLite table).

I'm getting a 'doc' variable just fine:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.blahblah/forex.xml"))
```

Have then tried this and variations of it:

```
doc.xpath('//fx:Container//Cube')
```

but keep getting empty collections.

I have genuinely tried all sorts of searches for examples of this that have been done previously, but cannot find anything which helps me.

Any assistance appreciated please.

EDITED:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class DevDataFeed
  def self.xml_parser
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.blahblah/ForEx.xml"))
    puts "doc class: " + doc.class.to_s
    block = doc.xpath("//fx:Container/Cube")
    puts "block class: " + block.class.to_s
    puts block.count

  end
end

datafeed = DevDataFeed.new
DevDataFeed.xml_parser
```

Output:

```
doc class: Nokogiri::XML::Document
block class: Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "empty collections?" Does that mean literally the call to `xpath(...)` returns a collection with no elements in it?

Comment: Can you show some of the code that uses the result from the call to `xpath`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt   Apologies, code sample and console output appended...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the namespace info to `xpath`, e.g.:

```
block = doc.xpath("//fx:Container/Cube", 'fx' => '???')
```

Or use:

```
block = doc.xpath("//*[local-name()='Container']/Cube")
```

Or remove namespaces altogether:

```
doc.remove_namespaces!
block = doc.xpath("//fx:Container/Cube")
```

Comment: That was nearly there, but gave me the push I needed, and I should have looked closer at XPath syntax (mea culpa). So to give me all Cube elements that have a 'time' attribute, what appears to work following a 'doc.remove_namespaces!' is 'doc.xpath("//Cube[@time]")